# I cannot solve the error "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:" in SVR | ML

Tags: machine-learning, svm, data-science

I'm trying to make a simple svr and the code requires some feature scaling , so when I apply the scaling to the dataset with this code it always gives this error !!
I have tried reshaping the data in `fit_transform()` function and also in the dataset split section but that always changes the values of y to absolute zero !! thou the values should range between `-0.720` and `2.643` ( total 10 values) ..

ps: the error comes when I fit and transform the 'y'.

I have seen different questions and applied techniques but idk that doesn't work for me , so please help as i'm stuck in it badly ...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[: , 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[: , 2].values

#feature scaling 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

#fitting svr to the dataset
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X,y)

#predicting a new result
y_pred = regressor.predict([[6.5]])

#visualising the svr results
plt.scatter(X,y ,color = 'red')
plt.plot(X , regressor.predict(X) , color = 'blue')
plt.title('truth or bluff')
plt.xlabel('positon level')
plt.ylabel('salary')
plt.show()
```

between -0.720 and 2.643 ( total 10 values)

Comment: dataset for y 45000
50000
60000
80000
110000
150000
200000
300000
500000
1000000

Comment: Please do **not** use the comments space for this kind of additional info - edit & update your code instead!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `y` is a `Series` or a `list` which is not accepted by `StandardScaler`. To convert `y` into an numpy array, run this:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.reshape(y, (-1,1))
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
```

Comment: thank you very very much Rajat :) much appreciated :)